# Continuous scrolling page using javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I am trying to repeat an animation where a page automatically scrolls to the bottom.  When it reaches the bottom I want it to then scroll to the top.  Then, repeat forever.  However,  I can't get it to even perform the first callback.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
pageScroll(pageScrollUp);





function pageScroll(callback) {
    window.scrollBy(0,1); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',50); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds

    callback(pageScroll);

}


function pageScrollUp(callback) {

    window.scrollBy(0,-1); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',50); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds

    callback(pageScrollUp);

}
```

Thanks
Josh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/8ZfKr/

```
var scrollDirection = 1;
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0,scrollDirection); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',50); // scrolls every 50 milliseconds
    if ( (window.scrollY === 0) || (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        scrollDirection = -1*scrollDirection;
    }
}
pageScroll();
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Is there an easy way to pause at the top and bottom?

Comment: inside the if statement you could clear the scrolldelay timeout and re-start it after a delay.

Comment: scrollDelay = 0;
setTimeout(scrollDelay = 50,1250);

Comment: While this clearly works in your example, it only manages to scroll faster rather than pause for me.  I will continue to play with it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: One of the comments is a little off.  It should say it's scrolling 1px pixel every 50 milliseconds, not every 100 milliseconds.